# MainActivity is too big. How do I split it into multiple files

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm building an Android App which has a complex screen with lots of logic.
It currently contains a listview, tabs, search box, and a panel for updating user stuff.
The probem is that the mainactivity code file became very big, although I'm seperating things to different layers, because there's a lot of UI components which affect things in the screen.

I'm trying to seperate it to several files but I don't seem to do it right.
As much as I understood Fragments is not what I need here. Are there any other ways?
Just need some directions please.

I'm asking mostly about the code, not the layout (Although I don't care changing the layout too).

Currently it's 616 lines and the biggest problem is that we are a team and the maintenance became hell...

Comment: You can start by posting your layout and your activity's class

Comment: What's big? xml or code?

Comment: How big is **too big**? 2000+ lines in Java is `ordinary business`.

Comment: Actually fragments could help you especially if you are using tabs. They are just another layer of abstraction with similar life cycles to activities. It could help if you post your class as well

Comment: @Funkystein Robert C. Martin might disagree

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments. I changed my question a bit so that it would reflect my prblem more clearly.

@jiduvah, that's exactly my question. What would bob do?

Comment: @jiduvah Are we talking about **theory** or the **real thing**?

Comment: @HagaiL Can you split up your layout into logical components? i.e. can you group the views in your layout into [composite views](http://lucasr.org/2014/05/12/custom-layouts-on-android/) to which you can delegate some logic and thus your activity only needs to deal with high-level concepts (`loginFormView.getCredentials()` vs getting the text from each edit text and validating in activity).

Comment: @Funkystein well I know we need to be pragmatic but I can't find any 2000+ line classes in any of my projects

Comment: @jiduvah same in any of ours, except when we (rarely) copy a class from the framework.

Comment: Have the main activity only manage the tabs and create separate fragments for every view

Comment: @Funkystein, you would be right but I would suggest thats not ordinary business.

Comment: I have a prblem managing a team which all work on the same file, and I need a solution that would seperate the files, so the religious debate about the length of the file here is not relevant...

Comment: **1** - Physically group the methods into meaningful classes (i.e. : Utility, Web, Graphics, ...). You are also allowed to use different folders in your project source, for a deeper code subdivision. **2** - Use NAMING CONVENTIONS (To easen the **logical access** to methods, constants, objects, ...). **3** - Abuse of COMMENTS. You might also include special markers for faster searches.

Comment: without seeing your code, what do you expect?

Comment: Thinking about everything you guys wrote here, and consulting some other guys, I come to believe that the answer for my issue is indeed Fragments. (Although the other answers do provide good techniques too)
@jiduvah I believe that you are the first who said that, can you please write it as an answer so that I would mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although 616 is not a particularly big file you could use Fragments as they just add another layer of abstraction. They also have a similar lifecycle to activities.

This tutorial shows how to add fragments to tabs

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Answer (score 3):

Create utility class and put your listeners and adapters there. Use main activity only to initialise view instances and setting listeners and adapters.

Comment: Are you offering to put all the click listeners in utility classes?!  Is that a common solution for my problem?
But if it affects other parts in the view, the utility class should be aware of it too.. wouldn't that make things even more complex?

Comment: If you click listeners are changing other views don't put it in utility class. But you can always create separate class for adapters.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base class put all the initializations and listerners there.
Likewise for function to be implemented later create a template in base class and override it in main activity. It works !